# lighttpd mod_cgi set http error from script

Tags: cgi, lighttpd

lighttpd mod_cgi is configured as following

```
server.modules += ( "mod_cgi", "mod_alias", "mod_setenv" )

cgi.assign += ( "" => "" )  ## run exectables with shebang

$HTTP["url"] == "network" {
   $HTTP["request-method"] == "GET" {
      alias.url += ( "network"  => "/usr/bin/network" )
      setenv.add-response-header = ( "Content-Type" => "application/xml" )
   }
}
```

when file `/usr/bin/network` returned error, lighttpd responds to client with `500 Internal server error`.

How can I handle that error and turn it into `400 Bad request` from cgi-script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script should always return 0. To set HTTP status use next approach.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Status: 400 Bad request"; echo
echo "message"
```

More samples and info about CGI are on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)